# GIFs are onion skinning in Java GUIs

Tags: java, project, gif

I'm using the GIF as an `ImageIcon`, is there a way I can stop this overlapping weirdness? The file itself doesn't overlap like it's displayed. If it helps, I also resized the image using `getScaledInstance`:

```
// Getting GIF and resizing it
ImageIcon yourPokemon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Eevee.gif"));
Image allYours = yourPokemon.getImage();
Image yoursISwear = allYours.getScaledInstance(288, 216, java.awt.Image.SCALE_FAST);
ImageIcon justTakeItAlready = new ImageIcon(yoursISwear);
JLabel Eevee = new JLabel(justTakeItAlready);
```

[Video in Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lbhglx4g0i9mnpe/Video.MOV?dl=0)

Comment: Have you tried without scaling? Or with scaling with SCALE_DEFAULT or SCALE_REPLICATE? Scaling gives these sorts of issues.

Comment: It does the same thing no matter how you scale it, even leaving it completely unscaled.

Comment: That suggests that the problem is not the scaling. Maybe it's the way you're painting the JLabel?  Is it moving while packing, or something like that?

Comment: Define packing? I'm putting the image on its own layer: 

// Adds fighting pokemon (layer 1)
eeveePokemon.add(Eevee); 

I'm not really doing anything else to it.

Comment: I was being generic about swing layouts. Packing is used by some layout managers to pack the widgets into the smallest space. If you're not using it, don't worry about it.